# handle different responses using mocha in nodejs unit testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js

my test is getting `passed`(`200 status code`), when i passing correct `header` information. but when i try with `wrong info`(`400 status code`), it can't able to handle that error,

this is my code,(here im passing wrong headers info, so response will be status 400 code)

```
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
chai.use(chaiHttp);
const main  = require('../server');
let token;
describe('GET USER', function()  {
  this.timeout(50000);
  it('Display info about user and returns a 200 response', (done) => {
    chai.request(main)
    .get('/users')
    .set("Authorization"," ")
    .then(function(response) {
      // Now let's check our response
      expect(response).to.have.status(200);
      done();
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
      expect(err.status).to.be.equal(400)
      done();
    })
  });
});
```

im getting error like this,

```
GET USER
(node:28390) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): AssertionError: expected undefined to equal 400
    1) Display info about user and returns a 200 response

  1 failing

  1) GET USER
       Display info about user and returns a 200 response:
     Error: Timeout of 50000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/test/users.test.js)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in another answer, you can't test 200 and 400 at the same time.

Calling `done()` prior to `expect` will result in test timeout if an assertion fails, because it throws assertion error and `done` is never called. This results in unhandled rejection, because there's no another `catch` after `catch`.

`chai-http` [supports promise control flow](http://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-http/#dealing-with-the-response---promises). Mocha naturally handles promises, a test should return a promise instead of using `done`. As it's [suggested](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-http/issues/75#issuecomment-340623621), error response can be reached as `err.response`. It likely should be:

```
describe('GET USER', function()  {
  it('should returns 400 response', () => {
    return chai.request(main)
    .get('/users')
    .set("Invalid header"," ")
    .catch(function(err) {
      expect(err.response.status).to.have.status(400);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a small misunderstanding here: the `catch` is not executed if `chai-http` receives an HTTP error. It is executed if the request fails. Getting `200` or `400` should both be tested in `then` and not catch.

As you can see from the error message, the `err` object does not have a `status` field because its not a `response` object but an instance of `Error`.

Comment: thanks for reply, can you help tell me, how to test 200 and 400 codes in same then, i didnot got any reference code, please help me

Comment: you should have two `it`s one with correct headers where you test `200` and one with wrong headers, where you test `400`. You cannot test both in the same `it`